# What is the equivalent for try-finally block in workflow foundation?

Tags: .net-3.5, workflow-foundation, sequential-workflow

There is a specific activity I want to execute even after exception has thrown, just like a `try{}finally{}` block.

Is it possible in sequential workflow using WF v3.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WF3 there is no such thing, that is something they added in WF4 though.

In Wf3 you would need to add a fault handler, execute your activity and use the ThrowActivity to throw the exception again.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but it's probably the correct one :)
I'm hoping we'll advance to wf4 soon.

Comment: You will get the TryCatch activity with a Finally block in WF4 :-) Just keep in mind that there is no guarantee there that the Finally executes if the exception was unhanded, it all depends on the hosts settings.